# Do i have to use "call{}" in a shared library when using it in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, dsl

I'm working on transforming a whole Jenkins from normal jobs to DSL/Pipelines. Had to implement a shared library for all the imports. In the said library there is a whole load of scripts.
Currently, all of them are set up like this:

```
package common

class Foo {
      static String bar(String text) {  stuff  }
      static String bar2(String text) {  stuff  }
      static String bar3(String text) {  stuff  }
}
```

And in the pipeline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library('jenkins-shared-libs') _
import common.*
```

There are many scripts and many methods. How, where, and can I not use call() to actually, "call" them?

Comment: "How, where, and can I not use call() to actually, "call" them?" - It is not clear what `call()` method you are talking about and it isn't clear what problem you are asking about.  Is it the case that where you have `import common.*` you intended to have `import static common.Foo.*`?

Comment: I'm not clear on what should i call when importing the library to the pipeline. The class? a method? do i need to create a script for each method by itself because they all have to be called 'call'?   i will try to add 'static'.

Comment: "do i need to create a script for each method by itself because they all have to be called 'call'?" - No.  None of the methods have to be called `"call"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to invoke the `bar` method in the `Foo` class you could do any of these:

**Option 1:**

```
common.Foo.bar('some argument')
```

**Option 2:**

```
import common.*

Foo.bar('some argument')
```

**Option 3:**

```
import static common.Foo.*

bar('some argument')
```